# Mocking a free function using Google Mocks

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have the following free function sig:

```
ReturnT getFirstAttributeHandle(ParentHandleT a, AttributeHandleT* b);
```

I need to pass the address of such a function to the constructor of an iterator which iterates over these handles. Since the concrete implementation of this functions accesses an external dependency, I need to mock it.

I'd like to use google mock to mock this function but I'm not sure how.

This is what I tried:

```
class IAttributeIterator
{
public:
    virtual ReturnT getFirstAttributeHandle(ParentHandleT a, AttributeHandleT* b) = 0;
};

class MockAttributeIterator : public IAttributeIterator
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(getFirstAttributeHandle, ReturnT(ParentHandleT a, AttributeHandleT* b));
};
```

And then something like this:

```
MockAttributeIterator i;
AttributeIterator iter = AttributeIterator(i.getFirstAttributeHandle);
iter++;
```

But this doesn't compile, giving the error:

'MockAttributeIterator::getAttribute': function call missing argument list; use '&MockAttributeIterator::getAttribute' to create a pointer to member

Any suggestion on how I might do this?

Comment: I renamed Iterator to AttributeIterator above. It is an input iterator.

Comment: Can you post the constructor of `AttributeIterator`? The declaration is enough

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not convert pointer to a member function to a function pointer (that is what the compiler is saying).

If the AttributeIterator's constructor accepts pointer to functions, then you need to create a fake function, which calls getFirstAttributeHandle method on MockAttributeIterator. Something like this :

```
namespace
{
    MockAttributeIterator mockObj;
    ReturnT FakeHandle(ParentHandleT a, AttributeHandleT* b)
    {
      mockObj.getFirstAttributeHandle( a, b );
    }
}
```

and pass pointer to FakeHandle to the constructor of AttributeIterator.

btw I just checked gmock faq, and this is even explained there ([here](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#My_code_calls_a_static/global_function.__Can_I_mock_it?) is the link).

There are few things :

- the code posted above is best to place in the anonymous namespace
- to clear the expectations between tests, in your setup method (every unit test framework has one), do this :

  ```
  void setUp()
  {
    ::testing::Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations( &mockObj ):
  }
  ```

Comment: Where would you place this code (the code in your post)? How will I reset mockObj between tests?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with google mock at all, the compiler was complaining about below statement:

```
AttributeIterator iter = AttributeIterator(i.getFirstAttributeHandle);
```

Pay attention to the expression as `i.getFirstAttributeHandle`, which is a **member function call**, so the compiler tried to match the function signature and get nothing.

If you want to pass **partially applied functions** safely to another class, try with `boost.function/bind` instead, playing with raw function pointers is quite dangerous and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the free function in a proxy class and then mock the call to the proxy method.
The following code outlines how you could do this to mock `CreateFileW` and `CloseHandle` calls in your code.

The basic idea is also outlined in the [gmock Cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions).

```
/// Common Interface
class IWindows
{
public:
    virtual HANDLE CreateFileW(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile) = 0;
    virtual BOOL CloseHandle(HANDLE hObject) = 0;
};


/// Implementation
class WindowsWrapper : public IWindows
{
public:
    WindowsWrapper(void);
    virtual ~WindowsWrapper(void);
    virtual HANDLE CreateFileW(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile);
    virtual BOOL CloseHandle(HANDLE hObject);
};

/// Mock
class MockWindowsWrapper : public IWindows
{
public:
    MockWindowsWrapper() {}
    virtual ~MockWindowsWrapper() {}
    MOCK_METHOD7(CreateFileW, HANDLE(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile))`
    {
        return ::CreateFileW(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
    }
    MOCK_METHOD1(CloseHandle, BOOL(HANDLE hObject))
    {
        return ::CloseHandle(hObject);
    }
};
```

Comment: you do not need constructor and destructor for the mock class. BTW a method with 7 parameters = big WTF